# Mystery Network Issue - 2 Computers on same switch - 1 pings entire network, 1 can only ping half

Tags: networking, router, ping, switch

I have been chasing demons for a week now. I have on e I can not understand for the life of me. I have 2 computers in my office. Originally I had them running off of a switch that was connected to the main switch connected to my router. One computer is able to ping all 40 plus devices on my network and the other is only able to ping half of those. I decided to bypass the switch and ran a new line for the second computer. If I plug that line directly into my router the computer pings the entire network. However if I run through my main switch, it again only pings 1/2. Anyon have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: What is this switch? Is the router the DHCP server for the entire network?